# Hot to debug a contract method invocation?

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

Running this code:

```
PrintProofOfWork.methods.printRequested(gcodeHash).send({from: web3.eth.defaultAccount})
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(`result of the invocation: ${result})`);
            });
```

prints nothing. I have no idea how to debug and understand what was not successful, in Etherscan can not see the transactions that I try to perform.

What can I do?

Comment: Add an `.error` clause, I'm sure it'll print something for you.

Comment: Using `PrintProofOfWork.methods.printRequested(gcodeHash).send({from: web3.eth.defaultAccount})
            .then((result) => {
                log(`result of the invokation: ${result})`.red);
            }).catch((err) => {
            log(`error occurred: ${err})`.red);
        });`

works fine and now I can see the error, thanks. Sorry, I am new in JS.